# Перевод объекта в строку

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код

```
const inputText = document.getElementById("text");
```

Он получает данные из инпута

Нужно превратить полученный объект в строку

P.S.: inputText.toString() не работает

Comment: `inputText.value`

Comment: Этим кодом вы получаете только элемент, а не его value.

Comment: inputText.value не работает, выдает Cannot read property 'value' of null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Он получает данные из инпута

Неверно! Он получает ***сам инпут***.

Для получения значения нужно воспользоваться свойством [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).

Comment: inputText.value не работает, выдает Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: Значит в разметке нет элемента с `id=text`

Comment: Ни val(), ни valueOf(), ни value не работают

Comment: @Leonid, ох а это уже хорошо замечено, потому что в этом то и проблема

Comment: Дык как же нам заметить если ничего не показываете!!!??